# How to call the function

Tags: unix

I am trying to invoke a function from command prompt, but I am not finding the correct way to invoke it.

This is my script:

```
echo "Hello World!" 

test {

    echo "Sample message"
}
```

---

I tried below ways:

```
sh-4.2$ main.sh test                                                                                                                                                     
Hello World!                                                                                                                                                             
./main.sh: line 5: usuage: command not found                                                                                                                             
A helpful message!                                                                                                                                                       
./main.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `}'                                                                                                                
./main.sh: line 8: `}'
```

---

```
sh-4.2$ . main.sh test                                                                                                                                                   
Hello World!                                                                                                                                                             
sh: usuage: command not found                                                                                                                                            
A helpful message!                                                                                                                                                       
sh: ./main.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `}'                                                                                                            
sh: ./main.sh: line 8: `}'
```

---

```
sh-4.2$ . main.sh test()                                                                                                                                                 
sh: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Can you please help me in this.

Comment: @Inian, just now added.

Comment: Use my answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of issues here, the syntax for `test` function is wrong, you need have the parentheses around,

```
test() {
    echo "Sample message"
}

export -f test
```

The `export -f` syntax allows you to export your functions to the shell; to run them from the command-line you need to source the script in the current shell as,

```
$ . ./main.sh
Hello World!
```

Now you can call the function `test` directly from the command line after having exported it from the script,

```
$ test
Sample message
```

Also a good practice to *NOT* have functions name `test`, because it is same name a `shell` built-in. Recommend using some custom names for that.